# AWS SQS (queue) with Spring Boot - performance issues

Tags: spring-boot, listener, message-queue, amazon-sqs

I have a service that reads all messages from AWS SQS.

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class JmsConfig {

    private SQSConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    public JmsConfig(
            @Value("${amazon.sqs.accessKey}") String awsAccessKey,
            @Value("${amazon.sqs.secretKey}") String awsSecretKey,
            @Value("${amazon.sqs.region}") String awsRegion,
            @Value("${amazon.sqs.endpoint}") String awsEndpoint) {

        connectionFactory = new SQSConnectionFactory(
                new ProviderConfiguration(),
                AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard()
                        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
                                new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey)))
                        .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(awsEndpoint, awsRegion))
                        .build());
    }


    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory =
                new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(this.connectionFactory);
        factory.setDestinationResolver(new DynamicDestinationResolver());
        factory.setConcurrency("3-10");
        factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        factory.setReceiveTimeout(2000L); //??????????
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate defaultJmsTemplate() {
        return new JmsTemplate(this.connectionFactory);
    }
```

I've heard about long polling so I wonder how I could use it in my case. I wonder how this listener works - I do not want to create unnecessary calls to the AWS SQS.

My listener that reads messages and converts them to the Object and saves on Redis db:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${amazon.sqs.destination}")
    public void receive(String requestJSON) throws JMSException {
        log.info("Received");
        try {
            Trace trace = Trace.fromJSON(requestJSON);
            traceRepository.save(trace);
```

(...)

I'd like to know your opinions - what is the best approach to minimalize unnecessary calls to SQS to get messages.
Maybe shoud I use for example

```
factory.setReceiveTimeout(2000L);
```

Unfortunately there is too little information in Internet about it

Thanks,

Matthew

Comment: did you find anything @Matley . Please share, i am trying to increase the TPS of listener. But all i can reach is to 80-90 TPS with concurrency